# Unable to activate environment conda - prompted to Run 'conda init' before 'conda activate' but it doesn't work

Tags: conda, miniconda, virtual-environment

Running Bash in Cmder on Windows 10. I am trying to activate a new virtual environment but keep getting told to run 'conda init' before 'conda activate'. I've tried running conda init but I keep getting prompted to do it again.

I'm guessing that it might have something to do with how I installed miniconda. I followed the instructions [here](https://nickeubank.github.io/practicaldatascience_book/notebooks/PDS_not_yet_in_coursera/00_setup_env/setup_python.html) which specifically states:

"On Windows, you’ll be asked if you want to add Miniconda to your PATH variable. Although it recommends that you do not do this, DO add it to your PATH. This will be important when we change how our command line works."

But when I read up on the conda documentation [here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment) it states:

"When installing Anaconda, you have the option to “Add Anaconda to my PATH environment variable.” This is not recommended because it appends Anaconda to PATH. When the installer appends to PATH, it does not call the activation scripts."

I'm guessing that this is the issue but I don't know of a work around (if one is needed). I am very new to coding.

**Actions and Errors below:**

I create my environment:

```
conda create --name test_env
```

The environment is created and then I am told to:

```
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate test_env
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate
```

I attempt to activate:

```
conda activate test_env
```

Ouput

```
CondaError: Run 'conda init' before 'conda activate'
```

I run 'conda init':

```
λ conda init
no change     C:\Users\Username\miniconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
no change     C:\Users\Username\miniconda3\Scripts\conda-env.exe
no change     C:\Users\Username\miniconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py
no change     C:\Users\Username\miniconda3\Scripts\conda-env-script.py
no change     C:\Users\Username\miniconda3\condabin\conda.bat
no change     C:\Users\Username\miniconda3\Library\bin\conda.bat
no change     C:\Users\Username\miniconda3\condabin\_conda_activate.bat
no change     C:\Users\Username\miniconda3\condabin\rename_tmp.bat
no change     C:\Users\Username\miniconda3\condabin\conda_auto_activate.bat
no change     C:\Users\Username\miniconda3\condabin\conda_hook.bat
no change     C:\Users\Username\miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
no change     C:\Users\Username\miniconda3\condabin\activate.bat
no change     C:\Users\Username\miniconda3\condabin\deactivate.bat
modified      C:\Users\Username\miniconda3\Scripts\activate
modified      C:\Users\Username\miniconda3\Scripts\deactivate
modified      C:\Users\Username\miniconda3\etc\profile.d\conda.sh
modified      C:\Users\Username\miniconda3\etc\fish\conf.d\conda.fish
no change     C:\Users\Username\miniconda3\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1
modified      C:\Users\Username\miniconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1
no change     C:\Users\Username\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\xontrib\conda.xsh
modified      C:\Users\Username\miniconda3\etc\profile.d\conda.csh
no change     C:\Users\Username\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
modified      HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun

==> For changes to take effect, close and re-open your current shell. <==
```

I exit out of the shell, reopen and run:

```
conda activate test_env
```

And again get

```
CondaError: Run 'conda init' before 'conda activate'
```

I have tried executing these steps in various orders and closing the shell vs not but I am stuck in the same loop.

Comment: Make sure the changes from running `conda init` had an effect on the shell you are actually using - you should see some new script code in the config file for the shell (for bash that would be in `.bashrc`, whereas powershell might use a `profile.ps1` script and so on....

Comment: @topsail can you expand on your direction a little more (sorry I'm super new)? If I'm running bash in cmder would I be looking in the cmder config file? I'm not exactly sure what I should be looking for. I see the new environment I created but I'm not sure where to look  to see if the `conda init` had an effect. Based on the output of running `conda init` I had assumed it made changes for everything listed as 'modified'.

Comment: if you are using bash in cmder (if you are using bash anywhere) you should have a bash configuration file. Typically in your home folder but actually depends on where cmder looks for its configuration files...!

Comment: See for example here: https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder#cmder-shell-user-config - specifically they are saying *Bash and Mintty sessions will also source the $HOME/.bashrc file if it exists after it sources $CMDER_ROOT/config/user_profile.sh*

Comment: If you find nothing in any of these config files you will have to fix them up "manually" but that should not be hard. I wrote up my own instructions [here](https://gist.github.com/northernocean/d0f7721ee7877094ba8b251202b71c0c), with some further links. It actually could be even simpler, by calling/invoking `conda.sh` rather than copying the contents of `conda.sh` into your `.bashrc`.

Comment: What all these config scripts do in a nutshell is just add conda to your path when you begin a bash session. To the shell it just "looks" like the environment variables exist in the environment, that's all - so conda will find the proper paths during bash sessions.

Comment: I discovered that I'm able to create and activate new envs in Anaconda Prompt and Powershell. I never got  bash/Cmder to work but it's not a huge issue I guess

Answer (score 3):

In MacOS, i use `conda init zsh`,and i get the following message. It works!

```
$ conda init zsh
no change     /opt/anaconda3/condabin/conda
no change     /opt/anaconda3/bin/conda
no change     /opt/anaconda3/bin/conda-env
no change     /opt/anaconda3/bin/activate
no change     /opt/anaconda3/bin/deactivate
no change     /opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
no change     /opt/anaconda3/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
no change     /opt/anaconda3/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1
no change     /opt/anaconda3/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1
no change     /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xontrib/conda.xsh
no change     /opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
modified      /Users/acookie/.zshrc

==> For changes to take effect, close and re-open your current shell. <==
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
conda init powershell
```

and restart powershell

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answers by wofy92 and acookie, the `conda init --help` says:

```bash
usage: conda init ... [SHELLS ...]
SHELLS    One or more shells to be initialized. If not given, the default value is 'bash' on unix and 'cmd.exe' & 'powershell' on Windows.
```

Not sure why it's not working to simply specify `conda init`, but you can try `conda init --all` to initialise all shells (`'bash', 'cmd.exe', 'fish', 'powershell', 'tcsh', 'xonsh', 'zsh'`) or specify your specific shell, such as `conda init bash`.

Comment: Yea I tried this method and it still have me issues. Creating and activating envs in Anaconda Prompt and Powershell seems to work, however, so I suppose that's just what I'll have to do.

Comment: @AlexAckerman Ah that's annoying. What shell are you using?